# Is there a bug in mysql8 json type while INSERT?

Tags: mysql

Here is DDL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `list_search_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

and when I insert data :

```
    INSERT INTO list_search_test
(id, name, info)
VALUES(4, 'jsonTest', 
'{"apis": [{"name": "BenefitService", "assetRef": false, "operations": [{"name": "createBenefit", "inputs": [{"name": "benefitid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Integer", "required": false}, {"name": "userid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": true}], "outputs": [{"name": "result", "intro": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": false}], "assetRef": false, "displayName": "", "dependencies": {"assetRef": false, "applicationServiceOperations": [{"bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/MODULE_CENTER/CampaignDomain/application-service|BenefitMgt|createUserBenefit", "version": "1.0.0"}]}, "requestMethod": "POST", "requestProtocol": "HTTP"}], "displayName": "", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter/business-capability-api"}], "name": "BenefitCenter", "appInfo": {"code": "benefitcenter", "version": "v1.0.0", "assetRef": false}, "bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter|BenefitCenter", "assetRef": false, "diagrams": [{"assetRef": false, "activities": [{"name": "createTest", "binding": {"assetRef": false, "apiOperations": [{"name": "BenefitService", "assetRef": false, "operations": [{"name": "createBenefit", "inputs": [{"name": "benefitid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Integer"}, {"name": "userid", "nameCn": "用户ID", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": true}], "outputs": [{"name": "result", "intro": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long"}], "assetRef": false, "displayName": "", "dependencies": {"assetRef": false, "applicationServiceOperations": [{"bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/MODULE_CENTER/CampaignDomain/application-service|BenefitMgt|createUserBenefit", "version": "1.0.0"}]}, "requestMethod": "POST", "requestProtocol": "HTTP"}], "displayName": "b", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter/business-capability-api"}]}, "assetRef": false, "displayName": ""}], "designerData": "{\"id\":\"s\"}"}], "sdkInfos": [{"id": "BenefitCenter", "bizCode": "BenefitCenter", "assetRef": true, "endpoint": "bw.app.bizworks.cn", "bizVersion": "V1.0.0", "downloadLink": "http://bw-paas.qa.console.aliyun.test/cloudapi-gateway-lite?Version=2016-07-14&Action=SdkGenerateForBizworks&RegionId=bizworks-premeses&ProjectCode=bizgo-ep&BizCode=BenefitCenter"}], "assetType": "BusinessCapability", "bizVersion": "V1.0.0", "displayName": "AI+】", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter"}');
```

bug mysql tell me :

```
Data truncation: Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 2177 in value for column 'list_search_test.info'.
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Strange error, as the JSON you are inserting validates and is valid JSON.

Comment: Don't those backslashes need to be escaped wit \\ for use in a MySQL query? MySQL has different escaping modes, one of them is using backslashes.

Comment: Use `"designerData": "{\\"id\\":\\"s\\"}"}` if you want the backslashes for the inner JSON string in "designerData".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with inner json.

designerData - For this you are  providing json string instead of actual json.

Working :

```
    INSERT INTO list_search_test
( name, info)
VALUES( 'jsonTest', 
'{"apis": [{"name": "BenefitService", "assetRef": false, "operations": [{"name": "createBenefit", "inputs": [{"name": "benefitid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Integer", "required": false}, {"name": "userid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": true}], "outputs": [{"name": "result", "intro": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": false}], "assetRef": false, "displayName": "", "dependencies": {"assetRef": false, "applicationServiceOperations": [{"bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/MODULE_CENTER/CampaignDomain/application-service|BenefitMgt|createUserBenefit", "version": "1.0.0"}]}, "requestMethod": "POST", "requestProtocol": "HTTP"}], "displayName": "", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter/business-capability-api"}], "name": "BenefitCenter", "appInfo": {"code": "benefitcenter", "version": "v1.0.0", "assetRef": false}, "bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter|BenefitCenter", "assetRef": false, "diagrams": [{"assetRef": false, "activities": [{"name": "createTest", "binding": {"assetRef": false, "apiOperations": [{"name": "BenefitService", "assetRef": false, "operations": [{"name": "createBenefit", "inputs": [{"name": "benefitid", "nameCn": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Integer"}, {"name": "userid", "nameCn": "用户ID", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long", "required": true}], "outputs": [{"name": "result", "intro": "", "assetRef": false, "dataType": "Long"}], "assetRef": false, "displayName": "", "dependencies": {"assetRef": false, "applicationServiceOperations": [{"bizCode": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/MODULE_CENTER/CampaignDomain/application-service|BenefitMgt|createUserBenefit", "version": "1.0.0"}]}, "requestMethod": "POST", "requestProtocol": "HTTP"}], "displayName": "b", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter/business-capability-api"}]}, "assetRef": false, "displayName": ""}], "designerData": {"id":"s"}}], "sdkInfos": [{"id": "BenefitCenter", "bizCode": "BenefitCenter", "assetRef": true, "endpoint": "bw.app.bizworks.cn", "bizVersion": "V1.0.0", "downloadLink": "http://bw-paas.qa.console.aliyun.test/cloudapi-gateway-lite?Version=2016-07-14&Action=SdkGenerateForBizworks&RegionId=bizworks-premeses&ProjectCode=bizgo-ep&BizCode=BenefitCenter"}], "assetType": "BusinessCapability", "bizVersion": "V1.0.0", "displayName": "AI+]", "targetNamespace": "http://www.103573587971.com/bizgo-ep/BUSINESS_CAPABILITY/BenefitCenter"}');
```

Comment: I know it.but i need string type here.